# How do I insert a Table of Contents reference for a page that does not yet exist?

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering

Basically, I need to insert a page before my table of contents -- this would be a PDF that cannot be modified and needs to contain the original text.  In my table of contents, I want to reference the page, but do not want a page number to appear beside it.

Currently I just have a `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter Name}` before my table of contents page, however it still displays the page number.

Is there a way to suppress the displaying of page numbers for specific TOC entries?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 4):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pdfpages}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{chapter}{\numberline {}Some pdf}{}}
\includepdf[pages=1]{pgfmanual}
\chapter{some section}
\chapter{another section}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I needed.  Thank-you.

Comment: @AnonYmous Glad I guessed it right, please remember that you can accept answers that best helped solve your problem (may be after a reasonable delay waiting for other answers) by clicking green check mark next to it. For details please read [How do you accept an answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer). Besides that, you can also upvote all useful answers :-)